# Loop using QGIS , GDAL

Tags: raster, qgis-processing, gdalwarp

I want to make many processes for multi raster , and i want to make a loop so it will continue , i want a general case so i can add on it for other . like Clipping as example , this is the code i get .

```
gdalwarp -q -cutline C:/Users/user/Desktop/IMG_DATA/AOI.shp -tr 10.0 10.0 -of HFA C:/Users/user/Desktop/IMG_DATA/T36PVC_20170329T080601_B08.jp2 C:/Users/user/Desktop/IMG_DATA/Clipped/b8.tif
```

Comment: You have many different options here. a) Run "Clip" as a batch process within QGIS; b) script the command within QGIS using PyQgis; c) script it using Python and run it as a standalone. It all depends on the exact task you want to perform, if the clipping extent alsways comes from the same shapefile etc.